# How to enable JMX on elastic beanstalk running amazon linux tomcat8

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8, jmx

I have to enable the following configuration for tomcat running in elastic beanstalk environment

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I have absolutely no idea where I have to make these changes.

```
Elastic Beanstalk Configuration

64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8
```

I believe elastic beanstalk create different set of folder structure for tomcat8

```
# whereis tomcat8
tomcat8: /usr/sbin/tomcat8 /etc/tomcat8 /usr/libexec/tomcat8 /usr/share/tomcat8
```

**My Issue is resolved** following this link
https://bobmarksblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/08/monitoring-elasticbeanstalk-tomcat-instances-using-visualvm-via-ssh/

Comment: Please write a brief description of the link in an answer (not editing the question) and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Note: it wouldn't work for load-balancing environments, when you have more than 1 node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a lot simpler than I thought.

To enable JMX in AWS Elastic Beanstalk you must add JVM command line configuration ->

```
Select Elastic Beanstalk environment -> 
Configuration -> Software Configuration -> 
Add following to “JVM command line options:”
```

in text box

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

It will automatically trigger the changes and will update the servers, now in a **security group** (assigned to your instances), you must allow this port 9000.

Now you can connect to any of the instances at a time but viewing is public IP address from AWS console (web).

Please have a look at this link for more details.
https://bobmarksblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/08/monitoring-elasticbeanstalk-tomcat-instances-using-visualvm-via-ssh/